# creating a nested json object with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, json

I have below snippet that I am supposed to create in objective-c.

```
   {
  "expression": "???=n1+n2+n3+n4",
  "terms": [
    {
      "name": "termsTitle",
      "term": [
        {
          "name": "answer",
          "value": "???"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my attempt to create it

```
NSMutableArray *terms= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *keysTerms = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"name", @"term", nil];


NSMutableArray *term= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *objectsTerms = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"answer",term, nil];

NSDictionary *termsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objectsTerms forKeys:keysTerms];

[terms addObject:termsDict];

NSDictionary *statement = [[NSDictionary alloc]
                           initWithObjectsAndKeys:expression,@"expression",
                           terms,@"terms",
                           nil];
```

I think I am close but for some reason, this is not working for me. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:terms] how can you do this ? terms is array not an integer

Comment: sorry that was supposed to be terms.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
NSDictionary* termDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[@"answer",@"???"] forKeys:@[@"name",@"value"]];

    NSArray* termArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:termDict, nil];

    NSDictionary* termsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[@"termsTitle",termArray] forKeys:@[@"name",@"term"]];

    NSMutableArray* terms = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:termsDict, nil];

    NSDictionary* result = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[@"???=n1+n2+n3+n4",terms] forKeys:@[@"expression",@"terms"]];

    NSLog(@"result: %@",[result description]);
```

The Result

```
2014-11-21 15:03:14.396 Answering_question[23716:113224] result: {
    expression = "???=n1+n2+n3+n4";
    terms =     (
                {
            name = termsTitle;
            term =             (
                                {
                    name = answer;
                    value = "???";
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @siu!!! This looks great and also it's a great example how I should be creating nested JSON in objective-c. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some problems with the structure you need to write more detailed code. Like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mainDict= [NSMutableDictionary new];
[mainDict setObject:@"???=n1+n2+n3+n4" forKey:@"expression"];

NSMutableArray *terms = [NSMutableArray new];

NSMutableDictionary *term = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[term setObject:@"name" forKey:@"termsTitle"];

NSMutableArray *subTerms = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableDictionary *subTerm = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[subTerm setObject:@"answer" forKey:@"name"];
[subTerm setObject:@"???" forKey:@"value"];
[subTerms addObject:subTerm];

[term setObject:subTerms forKey:@"term"];

[terms addObject:term];

[mainDict setObject:terms forKey:@"terms"];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mainDict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Output:

```
{
  "expression" : "???=n1+n2+n3+n4",
  "terms" : [
    {
      "termsTitle" : "name",
      "term" : [
        {
          "name" : "answer",
          "value" : "???"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```